# Google App Script function returns blank

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following function defined in Google App Script:

```
function getFinYear(date){

  var year = parseInt(date.getYear());
  var month = parseInt(date.getMonth());
  // month is zero based converting it to civilzation today mode
  month = month + 1;
  var fin = ""
  if(month > 7){
    if(year == 2011){
      fin = "Fin 2012";
    }
    else if(year == 2012){
      fin = "Fin 2013";
    }
    else if(year == 2013){
      fin = "Fin 2014";
    }
  }
  return fin;  
}
```

When I call this function from Google Spreadsheet I get nothing. I have a value as a date type in a cell. The actual value in cell `B2` is `12/03/2012`. I call it as `=getFinYear(B2)`

I can't seem to figure out why nothing appears.

I checked if the value is cached etc. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the type of cell B2 set as Date? If it is formatted as text, you could modify your function to include:

```
date = new Date(date);
```

Update: It looks like your spreadsheet is expecting date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: The function runs but i see nothing on the cell. Yes the type is date.

Comment: I just tried and am getting the correct result in the sheet. Could you share your Google Sheet?

Comment: Yes I can. [link](https://docs.google.com/a/bluepoint.net.au/spreadsheets/d/1vgHf9TypIvPJ3zmBmVU1q5yxuQjhGKoHVTDmtUK8sLE/edit#gid=0)